# How to implement a start/stop "button" in Android

Tags: java, android, textview, android-cardview

My goal is to have a [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView) that when is clicked, it goes from `Start` -> `Stop` and vice versa when clicked again. Inside the CardView I have two TextView which I would like to alter when it's clicked. The functionality behind this, would be to start a foreground service and stop it accordingly.

What I have in mind for the layout xml:

```xml
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardStartStop">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCardStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/card_start"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_start_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCardStop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/card_stop"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_stop_circle_black_24dp" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>
```

Then I thought to programmatically change the visibility of each TextView and persist its state using SharedPreferences when closing and re-opening app. My question is more at a design level, is there a better way to achieve this or I'm pointing in the right direction?

Comment: You can have only one `TextView` and change the text and drawable programmatically based on the value

Comment: Add layout `ConstraintLayout`  or  `RelativeLayout` under `Cardview`.

Answer (score 0):

Add one `TextView` and `setOnClickListener`

**XML File**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Start"
    android:id="@+id/text_start_stop"
  />
  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Class**

```
private TextView tStartStop;
Boolean flag = true;
```

**ClickEvent**

```
tStartStop = findViewById(R.id.text_start_stop);
tStartStop.setOnClickListener(view -> {
  if (flag) {
    flag = false;
    tStartStop.setText("Start");
  } else {
    flag = true;
    tStartStop.setText("Stop");
  }
});
```